# Use parameter to index into JSON object in Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I am creating an Azure deployment that will be used across the various regions. I am trying to keep the code agnostic to region and provide region specific info via a JSON file.

The JSON file will have the format of

```
{
    "region1":
        {
           "key" : "value"
        },
    "region2":
        {
           "key" : "value"
        }
}
```

I would like to import the JSON at deployment time and use the values for a specific region by taking an input of the target region to be deployed and storing it in the parameter called `region`. I then want to use the `region` parameter to index into the JSON object like the example below:

```
param _regions object = json(loadTextContent('<json_file_name>'))
param region string

var regionProperty = _regions.${region}.key
```

Using the syntax above for indexing into the JSON does not work, does anyone have ideas on how I can make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/data-types#objects):

> You can use the `[]` syntax to access a property.

```bicep
var regionProperty = _regions[region].key
```